# Python Class defining

Tags: python

What is wrong here:

```
 class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def greet(self, other_name):
        return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name,name)
```

Why isn't it working properly?

Comment: Can you give the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably mean:

```
return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, self.name)
```

you're missing the `self.` before the `name` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Attributes on the instance need to be referenced on the `self` argument:

```
def greet(self, other_name):
    return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, self.name)
```